# inserting row with values at certain index taking too long

Tags: python, pandas

I have following table:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| CarID  CarNumber   GPS     DateTime             Speed |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:10:51    21   |
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:10:54    23   |
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:10:59    23   |
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:11:01    24   |
| FBV404   404      105:59  04.02.2019 12:10:20    19   |
| FBV404   404      105:59  04.02.2019 12:10:25    19   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to insert row with zero values if `i+1` in CarNumber is not equal to `i` so I'd look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| CarID  CarNumber   GPS     DateTime             Speed |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:10:51    21   |
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:10:54    23   |
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:10:59    23   |
| WFV303   303      104:58  04.02.2019 10:11:01    24   |
| 0        0        0       0                      0    |
| FBV404   404      105:59  04.02.2019 12:10:20    19   |
| FBV404   404      105:59  04.02.2019 12:10:25    19   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried the following:

```
for i in range(len(df['CarNumber'])):
    if df['CarNumber'].iloc[i]!=df['CarNumber'].iloc[i+1]:
        zero_row = pd.DataFrame({"CarNumber":0,"DateTime": 0}, index=[i+0.5])
        df = df.append(zero_row, ignore_index=False)
        df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

I get no errors whatsoever but it takes really long time to process and never finishes (my csv file is ~50 mb).

What do I do about it and is there more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby`. This should at least be more efficient than looping through all rows.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'CarNumber': [303] * 4 + [404] * 2 + [405] * 5,
                   'othercol': range(11)})

def zero_row(cols, idx):
    return pd.DataFrame([[0] * len(cols)], columns=cols, index=[idx])

def add_zero_row(x):
    return x.append(zero_row(x.columns, x.index.max() + 0.5))

df = df.groupby('CarNumber').apply(add_zero_row)

# remove extra index from grouping
df = df.reset_index('CarNumber', drop=True)

# get rid of last zero row
df.iloc[:-1]
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for and it took 5 seconds
Thank you!

Comment: However, inserting zero rows to mark groups sounds somewhat unusual... may I ask what you are using this for, what the next steps are?

Comment: I then find time deltas for each car to see how much time it spent at certain location. The reason I added these zero value rows is that when I move, for instance, from car №303 to car №404,time delta for the start of car №404 will take into account the end time of car №303 which is wrong. Maybe there are any other way to address this problem?

Comment: just noticed, it doesn't take into account the dates. For instance, car log from 2019-02-04 to 2019-02-05 will give big time delta because dates are different but cars are the same. Do I group by dates as well?

Comment: You are looking at each car separately. In this case, you should probably use `groupby` by car (maybe even by location) and calculate the time difference directly in the function applied to the groups (like `add_zero_row` in my answer). Or, if I understand your problem correctly, you could even do: `df.pivot_table(index=['CarNumber', 'GPS'], values='DateTime', aggfunc=[min, max]).diff(axis=1)`.

Comment: What doesn't take into account the dates? If you are looking at days separately, then yes, you should also group (or pivot) by dates.

Comment: For example, car №303 stopped moving at 2019-02-04 16:41:05 and the next record in log for this car is 2019-02-05 08:18:16, the time when it started moving on 5th February, hence, the difference in time is almost 16 hours. How do I add zeroes before the start of each day?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202519/discussion-between-mdoskarin-and-mcsoini).

Comment: I suggest you open a new question describing what you want to do. In general, whenever you find yourself looping over the rows of a dataframe, there is most likely a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903884/how-to-account-for-the-different-dates-when-calculating-change